# @testing-library/react-native sequential fireEvent not working as expected

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, testing-libraryreact-native

I've been trying to make this testcase work by asserting if the next screen is getting called with correct country id and the fireevent doesn't seem to be working as expected.
this line:

```
fireEvent.press(await rendered.findByTestId('country-ID'));
```

should fetch the TouchableOpacity element with testID: 'country-ID' and then this line:

```
fireEvent.press(await rendered.findByText(i18n.t('btn_continue')));
```

should be called to call the navigate method that will be asserted like this:

```
expect(navigateMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith('SystemDowntimeScreen', {
  selectedCountry: 'ID'
});
```

When console.logged seems to be still sending `TH` in selectedCountry prop.

Here is the failing testcase:

```
it('Should navigate to SystemDowntimeScreen', async () => {
    const navigateMock = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(true);
    jest
      .spyOn(UINavigator, 'navigate')
      .mockImplementation(() => navigateMock());
    await act(async () => {
      fireEvent.press(await rendered.findByTestId('country-ID'));
      fireEvent.press(await rendered.findByText(i18n.t('btn_continue')));
    });
    expect(navigateMock).toBeCalledWith('SystemDowntimeScreen', {
      selectedCountry: 'ID',
    });
  });
```

I tried these:

- using `await waitFor()` individually for both fireEvents but no luck
- putting complete test in `await waitFor()`
- using `getByText()` and `getByTestId()` for fetching both the elements

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I was able to get it working by separating this `describe` from another scenario and put it into different file. Seems like didn't work due to some mock hijacking? Still open to suggestions for implementing proper solution for this